# Line Wrap Siunitx's \num macro

Tags: line-breaking, siunitx, inline, line

What is the recommended approach to have inline number wrap across line boundaries?  I was hoping that the `\num` macro took care of that, but it doesn't:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
XXX is a transcendental number which has an approximate value of 
\num{0.425185173296160641}\dots.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should line breaks be allowed only after groups of three digits? Should line breaks be allowed both in the integer and the decimal part of a number, or only in the decimal part?

Comment: I know that you know what you are doing, but ... should numbers be broken up like that in normal text?

Comment: @Mico: good questions. I think the ideal solution woudl allow for a line break between any group of three digits should (but perhaps not at the decimal point).

Comment: @Johannes_B: Please don't let my rep fool you into thinking that I know what I am doing. To answer your question, I guess it would be better to break the number instead of going over the margin, but am open to suggestions. Suprisingly, I haven't encoutered this problem before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following example allows line breaks between digit groups by smuggling a line break penalty in `group-separator`. Also the surrounding `\hbox` is removed from the text mode number is removed, otherwise the penalties would not have an effect inside a unbreakable box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*{\linewrapnum}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \num[#1,%
      mode=text,
      group-separator=\linebreak[1]\thinspace
    ]{#2}%
    \setbox0=\lastbox
    \unhbox0\relax
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
XXX is a transcendental number which has an approximate value of
\linewrapnum{0.425185173296160641}\dots
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Works great.  I think there should be an optional first paramater which gets passed as the frist optional paramaeter to `\num` so that the interface of `\num` and `\linewrapnum` is identical.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, done in updated answer.